# Как удалить ветку вложенного дерева?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как удалить элемент из массива, чтобы удалялись вместе с ним и все остальные дочерние элементы? Что неправильно делаю? Логика такая: при нажатии на кнопку delete если в селект боксе ничего не выбрано, то ничего не происходит, а если выбрано, то мы удаляем из массива выбранный элемент, проверяем есть ли у остальных элементов parentId такой же как id у удаленного, если есть то удаляем их тоже, и снова проверяем есть ли у оставшихся parentId как id удаленных. Понимаю что надо использовать рекурсию, но все мои попытки приводят к зависанию браузера на несколько минут, а то и больше. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно организовать удаление?

```js
var twigs = {
  "data": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Folder1",
      "parentId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Folder2",
      "parentId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Folder3",
      "parentId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Folder4",
      "parentId": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Folder5",
      "parentId": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Folder6",
      "parentId": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Folder7",
      "parentId": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Folder8",
      "parentId": 7
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "Folder9",
      "parentId": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Folder10",
      "parentId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "Folder11",
      "parentId": 8
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "Folder12",
      "parentId": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "name": "Folder13",
      "parentId": 4
    }
  ]
};

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $("#add").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var optionName = $("#title").val();
    var optionValue = twigs.data.length + 1;
    $("<option/>").attr('value', optionValue).text(optionName).appendTo("#parent");
    if ($("#parent").val() == 0) {
      twigs.data.push({
        id: twigs.data.length + 1,
        name: optionName,
        parentId: 0
      });
    } else {
      twigs.data.push({
        id: twigs.data.length + 1,
        name: optionName,
        parentId: parseInt($("#parent").val())
      });
    }

    $("#tree").html("");
    var tree = createTree(twigs.data);
    $('#tree').append(tree);
    $("#parent").val("");
  });





function deleteTwig() {
    var val = parseInt($("#parent").val());
    if (val !== 0) {
            for (var i in twigs.data) {
                deleted(i);
                function deleted(i) {
                    var id = parseInt(twigs.data[i]["id"]);
                    var parentId = parseInt(twigs.data[i]["parentId"]);
                    if (val === id) {
                        twigs.data.splice(i, 1);
                        if (id === parentId) {
                            deleted(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}


$("#delete").on("click", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   deleteTwig();
 });

  function createTree(data, parentId) {

    parentId = parentId || 0;
    var items = data.filter(function(elem) {
      return elem.parentId === parentId;
    });

    if (items.length === 0) return null;

    var tree = $('<ul>').addClass('tree');
    tree.append(
      items.map(
        function(elem) {
          $("<option/>").attr('value', elem.id).text(new Array(parentId + 1).join("-") + elem.name).appendTo("#parent");
          var li = $('<li>').append(
              $('<img src="images/folder.png">').addClass('state')
            ).append(
              $('<a>').html("<span>" + elem.name + "</span>").attr('id', elem.id).addClass('item')
            ),
            nestedTree = createTree(data, elem.id);

          if (nestedTree !== null) {
            li.append(nestedTree)
              .addClass('collapse')
          }
          return li;
        }
      )
    );
    return tree;
  }

  var tree = createTree(twigs.data);

  $('#tree').append(tree);

  $('#tree')
    .on('click', '.item', function() {
      $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    })
    .on('click', '.state', function() {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapse expand');
    })

});
```

```css
img {
  width: 20px;
}

select {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 173px;
}

button#add,#delete {
  width: 173px;
  height: 20px;
}

ul.tree {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

.active {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.state {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
}

.collapse>.state::after {
  content: '+';
}

.expand>.state::after {
  content: '-';
}

.collapse>ul {
  display: none;
}

.expand>ul {
  display: block;
}

.item {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="title">Title:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="title" name="title"><br>
<select id="parent">
        <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
    </select><br>
<button id="add">Add</button><br>
<button id="delete">Delete</button><br>
<div id="tree"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю что рекурсия должна выглядеть как-то так

```js
var twigs = {
  "data": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Folder1",
      "parentId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Folder2",
      "parentId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Folder3",
      "parentId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Folder4",
      "parentId": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Folder5",
      "parentId": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Folder6",
      "parentId": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Folder7",
      "parentId": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Folder8",
      "parentId": 7
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "Folder9",
      "parentId": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Folder10",
      "parentId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "Folder11",
      "parentId": 8
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "Folder12",
      "parentId": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "name": "Folder13",
      "parentId": 4
    }
  ]
};

// Функция найдёт элементы с указанными атрибутом и его значением
function findTwigs(attribute, value) {
  var result = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < twigs.data.length; i++) {
    if (twigs.data[i][attribute] == value) {
      result.push(twigs.data[i]);
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

// удалит текущий твиг и его потомков
function deleteTwig(id) {
  var twig = findTwigs('id', id)[0], // первый найденный элемент по "id"
      children = findTwigs('parentId', id); // его дети

  twigs.data.splice(twigs.data.indexOf(twig), 1); // удаляем найденный элемент
  
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    deleteTwig(children[i].id); // повторяем алгоритм для всех потомков
  }
}

deleteTwig(1);

document.write(JSON.stringify(twigs.data));
```

Comment: спасибо, Ваш код тоже работает)))

Answer (score 2):

Получилось что-то такое. При обходе, если находим искомую папку - удаляем ее, если дочернюю - добавляем ее id в очередь удаления и удаляем эту папку.

```
function deleteTwig() {
    var val = parseInt($("#parent").val());
    rmById(val);
}
function rmById(id) {
  var rmQueque = [id];
  for(var i = 0; i < rmQueque.length; i++) { // нельзя кэшировать rmQueque.length , т.к. добавляем элементы в очередь динамически
    for(var j in twigs.data) {
      if(twigs.data[j].id == rmQueque[i]) {
        // rm parent
        twigs.data.splice(j, 1);
      } else if(twigs.data[j].parentId == rmQueque[i]) {
        // rm child and add id to remove queque
        rmQueque.push(twigs.data[j].id);
        twigs.data.splice(j, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(twigs.data);
}
```

Comment: работает, но только для детей, а "внуки" остаются живы.

Comment: Поправил код, не тот id в очередь добавлялся